# get ajax success message in modal from controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.x

This is the Ajax code

```
$('#snd').click(function(){
    var e = $("input[id=mid]").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        url:"/mail/";
        data:{'valu': e},
        dataSrc : '',
        success: function(msg) {
            //table.reload();     
            //console.log(msg);
            $("#succModal").modal('show');
            table.ajax.reload();
        },
   });
});
```

This is the modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="succModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="succModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="succModalLabel">Customers</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="mg"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller code

```
try
{
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

The email is sent successfully. But no message is displayed. The modal is not displayed with the message. Please help me. Thank You

Comment: also tried by adding             success: function(msg) {
                            //table.reload();     
                            //console.log(msg);
                            $("#mg").html(msg);
                            $("#succModal").modal('show');
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        },

Comment: `$("#mg").html(msg);` should do the job, assuming that's the only element with "mg" on your page. Have you verified that `msg` is populated? What about if you move that line after the modal "show" command?

Comment: Have you looked at the response that comes back from this, using browser-side tools? You really shouldn't be echoing output directly from the controller, so by doing so you might be causing the browser to see it as something other than "success".